# any compiler that can do induction variable elimination?

Tags: gcc, compiler-optimization

It seems induction variable elimination is a well known compiler transformation, but I can't get the Intel compiler nor GCC to do it.

https://www.cs.utexas.edu/~pingali/CS380C/2013/lectures/strengthReduction.pdf

Here's my test program:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   typedef int64_t /*int32_t*/ LoopType;
   LoopType REPEATS = 1000000, N = atoi(argv[1]);
  int16_t *data = (int16_t *)alloca(N * sizeof(int16_t));
  for (int j = 0; j < REPEATS; ++j)
  {
    for (LoopType i = 0; i < N; i += (LoopType)8)
    {
      __m128i d = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i *)&data[i]);
      d = _mm_add_epi16(d, d);
      _mm_storeu_si128((__m128i *)&data[i], d);
    }
  }
  return data[5];
}
```

assembly code for inner most loop:

```
..B1.4:                         # Preds ..B1.2 ..B1.4
        movdqu    (%rsi), %xmm0                                 #50.30
        incq      %rdi                                          #53.5
        paddw     %xmm0, %xmm0                                  #56.11
        movdqu    %xmm0, (%rsi)                                 #50.30
        addq      $16, %rsi                                     #53.5
        cmpq      %rdx, %rdi                                    #53.5
        jb        ..B1.4        # Prob 82%                      #53.5
```

What I want is for the compiler to replace the loop counter i with the pointer expression &data[i]. I recognize there's a gotcha (overflow) that prevents the compiler from doing that transform. But I also found out GCC has a flag -funsafe-loop-optimizations that assumes overflow won't happen.

But that didn't help. I've tried compiling the code above with both ICC 14 and GCC 4.9 and it always results in 2 induction variables (usually 7 instructions) compared to 6 if I manually use a pointer as the loop condition.

I've tried changing the loop type from int64 to int32 and changing the for loop to a do - while (1 fewer branch) but that didn't help either.

Performance wise, I found there's no difference from saving 1 instruction:

output of Linux perf for N = 32768

```
8,687,218,116 cycles                    #    2.103 GHz
   485,770,953 stalled-cycles-frontend   #    5.59% frontend cycles idle
    29,257,198 stalled-cycles-backend    #    0.34% backend  cycles idle
28,684,643,143 instructions                   #    3.30  insns per cycle
```

output of Linux perf for N = 32768, after replacing loop condition i with pointer

```
  8,292,816,300 cycles                    #    2.102 GHz
       102,773,625 stalled-cycles-frontend   #    1.24% frontend cycles idle
        29,845,621 stalled-cycles-backend    #    0.36% backend  cycles idle
    24,586,051,519 instructions              #    2.96  insns per cycle
```

This makes sense because instruction level parallelism means the extra add won't increase the critical path. But it will free up a register which is a good thing.

I also realize that if you have > 1 array expression in your loop, then induction variable elimination wouldn't help reduce # instructions, since it would be cheaper to have 1 counter and use register + register addressing for array indexing.

So it seems the benefit of induction variable elimination is limited. Can someone confirm whether or not induction variable is implemented in any compiler and how to get it to work? I want to know because I have to decide whether to manually do this optimization to the detriment of readability, or keep using counters and hope that some future compiler will be able to optimize it.

Comment: The link to utexas.edu is broken.

Comment: Strength reduction says `replace expensive operations (multiplications) with
cheaper ones (additions) in definitions of induction variables`.  Are you sure that making that substitution is actually cheaper on the CPU you are targeting?  It could be that the compiler is aware of the optimization but opts not to use it.  Your own measurements show no performance gain in this scenario.

Comment: I agree it's not a win in most cases (especially in the example) but I did see a noticeable gain by doing this manually. It was for loop inside a large function, so I'm guessing  freeing up 1 register reduced some spills and reduced code size as well.